Disable MacVim when using Finder context menu item: Open in Terminal
The context menu (i.e. right-click menu) on the Finder Pathbar includes the option: Open in Terminal. But when I try to use it, the file or folder selected gets opened in MacVim. I guess I set that behavior somewhere some time ago, but I don't remember and I want to reset it back to the default (i.e. to actually open the item in terminal, not MacVim). I've looked over my .bash_profile and .bashrc and .vimrc but I don't see anything related.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
UPDATE: added screenshot of info panel for folders, which shows there is no 'open with' option.
This post (below) describes a similar problem, but for iterm2. But the solution, which involves items in the Application Support folder, does not help because there is no Application Support item for MacVim.
Can not change "Open in Terminal" default back to Terminal from iterm2

I also looked at the MacVim settings menu. I should add that Finder > Services > New Terminal at Folder works as desired.


Despite the fact that it only shows up on folders, the behavior of the button is tied to what the "Unix Executable File" file type is to be opened with. I probably changed it when inspecting some scripts. To fix it, find any file that the system sees as "Unix Executable File" (such as extension-less shell scripts), open "Get Info" on such a file, change the "Open with:" selection to "Terminal.app", and finally click "Change All...".

https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/1eu656z/fyi_cause_and_fix_for_finder_path_bars_open_in/

Good suggestion. But it seems folders don't have an 'open with' option. So my folders open as MacVim text files.

That Reddit poster seems to be describing the same problem you have, but with TextEdit instead of MacVim. Did you try his solution?

Yes, as I tried to explain, folders don't have an 'open with' option. The problem affects both text files and folders. For example, I want to open a terminal at a specific directory, but can't because it goes to MacVim.

I updated my post with a screenshot to illustrate my point

I know there is no open-with setting for folders. I never said there was. You’re not doing what was suggested above.

reading the suggestion more carefully, and doing it exactly as suggested (i.e. using a script with no extension), solved the problem.
